# how to understand the significance of dynamic multiplier?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

In below figure, it is written that the results of the dynamic multiplier are significant. How would we reach that kind of result by looking at dm tables?

[image: stata dm exmaple]

Comment: The upper and lower bounds are the same positive or negative, so dynamic multipliers are different from 0.

Comment: Please type out all questions for the benefit of users who cannot read the image. https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/121522